# Setting variable based on a folder at a particular path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a situation where I need to set a variable **%%DC%%** in a batch file based on the latest folder at a particular path.

**EX:**

1. C:\Program Files\ProgramName\CommonData
2. C:\Program Files\ProgramName\M010
3. C:\Program Files\ProgramName\M020
4. C:\Program Files\ProgramName\M030

There is also a possibility for other folders to be located within the same folder (**ProgramName**), so I need it to only return the latest software build folder that begins with “**M**”.

Since “**M030**” would be the latest in this case I need **%%DC%%** to equal **M030**. There may be cases where not every machine would be at the same software app build package so, I need it to return the latest build “**M**" folder on that particular machine.

Comment: please post some code you already have

Comment: Here you go I hope it helps.

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1" %%i in ('dir /B /ON "C:\Program Files\PTC\Creo 3.0\"') do set DC=%%i

copy /Y \\ServerName\pro_stds$\creo\mech_creo3\feature.dat "C:\Program Files\PTC\Creo 3.0\%DC%\Common Files\mech\text\licensing\mech\feature.dat"`

Comment: @Bill, edit your original question and put the code in there.

Comment: @Bill, your code should be working but to be on the safe side I would change the FOR /F command to this. `for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /ad /B /ON "C:\Program Files\PTC\Creo 3.0\M*"') do set DC=%%i `

Comment: Thank You, that worked great......

Comment: Please specify the term "latest" - is it the greatest number or the most recent creation/modification date??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bill, your code should be working but to be on the safe side I would change the FOR /F command to this.

```
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /ad /B /ON "C:\Program Files\PTC\Creo 3.0\M*"') do set DC=%%i
```